# Javascript Math.ceil weird round up issue

Tags: javascript

can anyone explain why the result bellow in JS?
console.log(Math.ceil(1.22222 * 100000));
// Expect 122222 in my code, surprisingly, it is 122223

console.log(Math.ceil(1.222222 * 1000000));
// Expect 1222222 and it is 1222222

why 5 and 6 decimal points have different outcome?????????????????

Comment: https://floating-point-gui.de/basic/